# How do I allow the user to multi-check with the CheckedListBox through the 'shift' key?

Tags: c#, winforms

Say that I have a CheckedListBox with items "1", "2", "3", "4", and "5" in that order and I want to select "2", "3", and "4" by selecting "2" then holding shift and selecting "4".  Is there any built-in way to achieve this with the CheckedListBox control?  I found an article on how to use the SelectedIndexChanged event to get close to this behavior, but though it checks multiple items, it does not show them as selected.

http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/multiple-selection-checkbox-53049.shtml

If there is an alternative control that I could use then I would be up for that as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There might be an easier alternative, but you could use a `ListView`, set `CheckBoxes` to `true`, `HeaderStyle` to `None`, and `View` to `List`.

Correction:

Should have been set `View` to `Details`.

Comment: In my actual scenario, I have a large list of file names that will be the data.  If I use the ListView, how do I set it to only be vertically scrollable and only have a single column of items?

Comment: Now that I think about it more, a ListBox is probably what I need.  There's no reason to have checkboxes.  They just need to select some files from a list.  Thanks for the help though.  Your answer would work for the test scenario from my original question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  You want to set `View` to `Details`.  Assuming only a single column, you can also set the width of the Column to allow for the vertical scroll bar, getting the scroll bar width using `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`.

Comment: Great solution! At first, when I switched `View` to `Details`, the ListView remained blank, but as soon as I added a column in the `Columns` property it worked fine

Answer (score 14):

Multiple selection is not supported, but i got here by search to find the CheckedItems.

The selected items refers to the items that are marked, the checked items refers to the items that are checked.

Hence use .**CheckedItems** property instead of .SelectedItems if you want the items with a checked checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

for the multichecks i came up with this today:

```
    List<int> listBox2_selectionhistory = new List<int>();

    private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int actualcount = listBox2_selectionhistory.Count;
        if (actualcount == 1)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
            {
                int lastindex = listBox2_selectionhistory[0];
                int currentindex = checkedListBox2.SelectedIndex;
                int upper = Math.Max(lastindex, currentindex) ;
                int lower = Math.Min(lastindex, currentindex);
                for (int i = lower; i < upper; i++)
                {
                    checkedListBox2.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
                }
            }
            listBox2_selectionhistory.Clear();
            listBox2_selectionhistory.Add(checkedListBox2.SelectedIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox2_selectionhistory.Clear();
            listBox2_selectionhistory.Add(checkedListBox2.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
```

as far as i know checkedlistboxes' SelectionMode can only be either one or none which means you can never make the app select more than 1 at a time (I also used this behavior to simplify my code for checkedlistboxes)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like multiple selection is not supported for the `CheckedListBox` control (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode.aspx)). It does support multiple checkboxes being checked, but not multiple items being selected (highlighted) at once.

I agree with the other answer that a `ListView` is probably the best way to get both checkboxes and multiple selection.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it it not possible to set see the remarks section in [CheckedListBox.SelectionMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode.aspx)

For an easier alternative follow the adivice of adrift.

Answer (score 2):

[image: CheckedListBox]

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox LBO1;

 string mySentLst = string.Join(";", LBO1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: This question from 7 years ago was about "selecting" multiple items.

Comment: That's obvious.  None of the answers are complete though.  The multiple selected CheckedItems are useless unless you get them Cast(ed) into a type!!  Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps:

- Select `CheckOnClick` = true.
- When you want to retrieve selected item, use `GetItemChecked(int index)` method instead.