# how can I find out which items are selected in checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have a **checkedlistbox** in C# language, that I want to have multiselection,

but the problem is when I type **checkedlistbox.SelectedItems** , it only contains properties of last selected item.

Whats the solution ?

Comment: [CheckedListBox.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode.aspx) of your checkedlistbox to `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended` to enable multiple selection.

Various modes -

> - One - Only one item can be selected.
> - None - No items can be selected.
> - MultiSimple - Multiple items can be selected.
> - MultiExtended - Multiple items can be selected, and the user can use the SHIFT, CTRL, and arrow keys to make selections

**EDIT**

You can't set multiple selection for checkedListBox as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode.aspx) -

> The SelectionMode property determines whether one item in the list box
>   can be selected or no items can be selected. For CheckedListBox
>   objects, multiple selection is not supported. You can set the mode to
>   one item or no items.

Even I tried setting it and as stated it throws ArgumentException at runtime -

[image]

Comment: Oh i got it, but when i type checkedlistbox.selectedmode there are lots of options but there is no multisimple or multiextended

Comment: Are you sure? I am able to see only four stated modes above. But like i mentioned you can't set it to multiple even if it is visible.

Comment: So if i can not have multiselection, how can i have it in a single form in visual studio using C# ?

Comment: You are using `WPF` or `WinForms`?

Comment: i am using windows forms

Comment: You can customize `ListView` to fit your needs. Refer to answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3833556/632337